# How to use Meld as git mergetool & difftool on WSL2?

Tags: git, windows-subsystem-for-linux, meld, wsl-2

From WSL2 (Ubuntu) how could one use Meld installed natively on Windows as the git merge and diff tool?
So that commands like `git mergetool` & `git difftool` from WSL open Meld on Windows.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Make `meld` easily accessible in WSL by linking it:

```
sudo ln -s /mnt/c/Program\ Files\ \(x86\)/Meld/Meld.exe /usr/local/bin/meld
```

In WSL edit `~/.gitconfig` and add:

```
[diff]
        tool = meld
[difftool "meld"]
        cmd = meld \"$(wslpath -aw $LOCAL)\" \"$(wslpath -aw $REMOTE)\"
[merge]
        tool = meld
[mergetool "meld"]
        cmd = meld --auto-merge \"$(wslpath -aw $LOCAL)\" \"$(wslpath -aw $BASE)\" \"$(wslpath -aw $REMOTE)\" --output \"$(wslpath -aw $MERGED)\" --label=Local --label=Base --label=Remote --diff \"$(wslpath -aw $BASE)\" \"$(wslpath -aw $LOCAL)\" --diff \"$(wslpath -aw $BASE)\" \"$(wslpath -aw $REMOTE)\"
```

To make `git difftool --dir-diff` work you need to use it with `--no-symlinks` (the symbolic links in `\\wsl$\` don't seem to currently work when opening from Windows apps). Changes will still be copied back to the source files once Meld is closed. Since I use git dir diff tool a lot I've added these aliases in the above file:

```
[alias]
        dt = !git difftool --dir-diff --no-symlinks -t meld
        mt = !git mergetool -t meld
```

Comment: That's so Inception-y